# Getting the SQL exception error in PowerApps

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

I have an simple SQL error displayed on my screen.

It's a violation of a primary key - that's all it is.

I am using application insights to log all the errors but it seems the error is split into different parts. It seems the server response is the area within the error that gives the most information. I cannot seem to get that in application insights.

I just get this in the application insights :

```
[{"Message":"The requested operation is invalid."}
```

Which is guess is the PowerApps generic error and the server is error is what I want.

I am using a collection to store all the errors from the patch like this:

```
Collect(PatchErrors,Errors(Persons));
```

Persons is the SQL tables and PatchErrors is just the name of the collection. The collection has these rows in it:
Column, Error, Message, Record - which makes sense from the Microsoft articles.

And then I am using a Trace command to push to application insights :

```
Trace(
"Patch to the SQL Error",
TraceSeverity.Critical,
{
UserName: User().FullName,
Error: PatchErrors.Error,
Message: PatchErrors.Message,
Record: PatchErrors.Record,
Column: PatchErrors.Column
}
```

I am not just seeing the server error at all and I cannot find it in the Error function.

Comment: Can you give us the query you are trying to run, the table definition(s) and some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

```
Collect(PatchErrors,Errors(Persons));
```

This line states an array of items is being collected, since you don't clear the collection before doing something with it.

```
{
  Message: PatchErrors.Message
}
```

This expects a record to be processed, not an array.

First( PatchErrors ).Message for example should you you the message.

Comment: I have done al of that and its fine - i understand that completely... The message does not bring in the error from the server - like 'cannot add a duplicate ID of 1 (ie a sql constraint). I can also get error code 8 (which is a constraint has occured) but i cannot get the exact server error... I dont really need an error has occured and ID of 8 - i need the server error from SQL, stored in a collection and then push to application insights.

Comment: Do you use Power Automate to run the query?
Do you use a custom connector?
Have you verified with the browser editor tools what the trace returns?